# How to print the strings in new line in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have written a for loop inside which i wish to print a statemnt that is like this

```
for i in ...
do
echo -e "`date +%Y%m%d`:`date +%H%M%S`;"$i".dat\n"
done
```

basically i want the output in this format for every value of i

```
20140619:130920:Paris
20140619:130921:London
20140619:130922:New York
```

Please help me where im going wrong.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Use `echo "`date +%Y%m%d`:`date +%H%M%S`;"$i".dat"`

Comment: add a `sleep 1` after the `echo` line? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for i in listofcities
do
    echo $(date +%Y%m%d)":"$(date +%H%M%S)$i"\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try single date command

```
  $-for i in Paris London "New York";do echo "`date "+%Y%m%d:%H%M%S:$i"`" ;sleep 1 ;done
```